# PHP Routing: use SQL result as "router"

Tags: php, sql, routes, switch-statement

I have the following index.php:

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

require_once "sql.php";
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);
$urls = $link->query("SELECT URL FROM TEST");

    switch ($uri) {
    case "/":
    header("location: http://www.mysite.com/en/index.php");
    break;

    while($rurl = mysqli_fetch_array($urls)){
        case $rurl['URL']:
            header("location: http://www.mysite.com/folder/page.php?test=$rurl['URL']");
         break;
    }

    default:
        include "errors/404.php";
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    break;
}
?>
```

I get a couple of errors on the while loop. How can I insert a "case:" into the while?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want the case inside the while loop?
You could use an

```
if (!empty($rurl['URL']))
```

(Not sure i am getting what you are trying to do)

Comment: If the URI is equal to one of the database results, then redirect to the page.

Comment: I think i get what you are trying to do, you should get the uri, escape it, and insert it in to the clause SELECT URL FROM TEST WHERE URL = $URL get the result, and redirect to that page